# How to Re-Initialize the UI Element?

Tags: wpf

I have the Text with some Properties (Width, Height, Default Text) in the XAML Designer, At the Run-time scenario i have changed some properties for specification. How to rollback the changes to original state as like the UI which are designed initially in the xaml Window via button click in Runtime.

Comment: these values are not stored anywhere so you eighter have to store them maually, reload the entiere window or create a new control while romoving the modified one

Answer (score 0):

The original values are not stored anywhere, so some ideas of what you could do:

- If you are using MVVM, you could set the `DataContext` to a new instance
- If you are using code behind you could create a new instance of the `UserControl`/`Window`
- You could store the original values manually and write a method to set these properties to their defualt values
- You could use the [DefaultValueAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to define the default values, here is some sample code of how it can be used given in the docs:

  ```
  [DefaultValue(false)]
  public bool MyProperty
  {
      get
      {
          return _myVal;
      }
      set
      {
          _myVal = value;
      }
  }


  // Gets the attributes for the property.
  AttributeCollection attributes =
      TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["MyProperty"].Attributes;

  /* Prints the default value by retrieving the DefaultValueAttribute 
   * from the AttributeCollection. */
  DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute =
      (DefaultValueAttribute) attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
  Console.WriteLine("The default value is: " + myAttribute.Value.ToString());
  ```

  With this you could easily write a static method to set each property to their default value.